# Cannot access env variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm have an issue in accessing the env variables from env file in Laravel.
The application is already hosted to one of shared hosting sites.
When I printed the `APP_KEY` variable, it returns empty.

I tried to check if the env file exists by using `file_exists` function inside the `index.php` file in the public directory and it returns `true` yet I cannot access the env variables. 
Thus, resulting to error in cipher because of empty appkey.

This happened after this code block in the `index.php` file in the public directory:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

When I print the `$response->send()`, it showed the cipher error.

I did the same thing in my local and it displayed the appkey value with no cipher error.

The files I used in the shared hosting site are the same files from my local. This is the first time I host the Laravel application. Maybe there are some things I missed?

Do you have any idea why this happening? Thanks.

Comment: so just run `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: But the application is already hosted.

Comment: The key refresh shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: @Option I think the key is already there, but he is not able yo fetch its value from `env` file

Comment: I generate another key in my local and pasted the same in the hosted application but still the same or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @Mayank, I have ran into this before and by running a new key generate it worked for me.

Comment: Yes @MayankPandeyz. It's already there.

Answer (score 9):

try use

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 4):

A possibility is that config caching is enabled. In that case, only `env` calls in the `config/` dir return a value.

This is cryptically explained in the config docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files.

Comment: So env values can be only called inside the config files?

Comment: correct, so make sure to put all the env values you need in config files so your application can use them.
btw, you can run an `php artisan config:clear` and see if your env calls work then

Comment: thanks, this actually really helped me out. I had been looking for a solution all morning. it is now 3pm.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 there have an issue, you cannot get the env variable direct assign `env("URL")`

To simplify:

**Step 1**.) Add your variable to your .env file, for example,

> `URL="http://google.com"`

**Step 2.**) Create a new file inside of the config folder, with any name, for example,

> `config/getURL.php`

Step 3.) Inside of this new file, I add an array being returned, containing that environment variable.

> `<?php return ['url' => env('URL') ];`

**Step 4.**) Because I named it "getURL", my configuration 'namespace' is now an example. So now, in my controller I can access this variable with:

> `$url = \config('getURL.url');`

Step 5.) Now you can we env variable in the controller

> ```
> public function url() {return config('example.url');}
> ```

Finally, Clear the cache:

> `PHP artisan config:cache`